# Windows' USB Audio Codec summing audio inputs

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, audio, codec

I set up a small video conferencing room with a USB webcam (Logitech BRIO) and a hardware audio mixer (Behringer Xenyx QX1204 USB) to support several (analog) microphones (Rode Wireless GO via VXLR adapters). The PC, the mentioned peripherals are connected to, runs Windows 10 Education (which is a variant of Windows 10 Enterprise).

Both webcam and audio mixer are connected via USB. The webcam is listed as an audio input/microphone and when connecting the audio mixer, an additional audio input named `USB Audio Codec` is shown.

However, the `USB Audio Codec` does not only contain the audio signal from the connected hardware mixer, but rather consists of a mix/sum/overlay of the webcam's and the mixer's audio signal. If the webcam is unplugged/disconnected, the `USB Audio Codec` only consists of the mixer's signal.

I was not able to connect other USB audio sources in addition to the mixer and the webcam, but from the behavior I encountered, I would assume that `USB Audio Codec` contains *all* connected USB audio input devices and not only the mixer. With the mixer unplugged, but the webcam connected, `USB Audio Codec` is not shown as an audio input. Therefore, the driver activation of `USB Audio Codec` seems to be related to my hardware mixer and shows undesired (faulty ?) behavior with the webcam connected.

Is there a way to separate the mixer audio input from the webcam audio input when using `USB Audio Codec`? Or more general: Is `USB Audio Codec` always summing all USB audio inputs and is there a way to separate the contained signals by its 'real hardware source'?